# BigQuery Standrad SQL How to transpose a row into a column

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to use the new Standard SQL feature in BigQuery. However, I cannot happen to find reference in the documentation as to how to do the following:

The input I have is:

[image]

I am trying to transpose it to the following:

[image]

I was hoping to use PIVOT functions as in SQL, but I cannot happen to find how creating PIVOTs works in the BigQuery Standard SQL feature.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the option below

Number of rows you have in YourTable doesn't matter here  - but number of column Does!

You will need to maintain ARRAY creation under temp named subquery by having as many SELECTs as columns you have to transpose. In below example there are three as it is in your question.

There is no way to `avoid the manual work` for this part rather then by coding in client of your choice - by loading table schema with [tables.get API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/get) and looping through [schema's fields](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#schema) while building below query and then finally running it.
Again - this requires client coding, which doesn't look like what you are looking for here

So, here we go:

```
WITH temp AS (
  SELECT B, 
    ARRAY(
      SELECT AS STRUCT 't1' AS B1, t1 AS Value UNION ALL 
      SELECT AS STRUCT 'm1' AS B1, m1 AS Value UNION ALL 
      SELECT AS STRUCT 'p1' AS B1, p1 AS Value
    ) AS bb  
  FROM YourTable 
)
SELECT B, bb.B1 AS B1, bb.Value AS Value 
FROM temp t, t.bb
```

You can test it with

```
WITH YourTable AS (
  SELECT 'a' AS B,  1 AS t1,  2 AS m1,  3 AS p1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b' AS B,  4 AS t1,  5 AS m1,  6 AS p1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c' AS B,  7 AS t1,  8 AS m1,  9 AS p1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'd' AS B, 10 AS t1, 11 AS m1, 12 AS p1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'e' AS B, 13 AS t1, 14 AS m1, 15 AS p1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'f' AS B, 16 AS t1, 17 AS m1, 18 AS p1 
),
temp AS (
  SELECT B, 
    ARRAY(
      SELECT AS STRUCT 't1' AS B1, t1 AS Value UNION ALL 
      SELECT AS STRUCT 'm1' AS B1, m1 AS Value UNION ALL 
      SELECT AS STRUCT 'p1' AS B1, p1 AS Value
    ) AS bb
  FROM YourTable 
)
SELECT B, bb.B1 AS B1, bb.Value AS Value 
FROM temp t, t.bb
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not Pivoting, it's UNION (comma operation)

Use simple union for

```
select B\B1 as B, 't1' as B, t1 as value,
select B\B1 as B, 'm1' as B, m1 as value,
select B\B1 as B, 'p1' as B, p1 as value;
```

Comment: This works, however the table I provided is a simplified version of the table I  have to do this for. I have hundreds of B\B1s values and I need to avoid the manual work.

Comment: There is no syntax in database to write SQL code for you. You will need to use a coding language to generate the SQL syntax for this case.

Comment: I was fearing I will have to resort to that. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I get a `Syntax error: Expected keyword FROM but got keyword SELECT at [line]`